# Is there a vertical equivalent for \rlap?

Tags: macros, vertical-alignment

I'm looking for some sort of vertical equivalent for `\rlap`, which can be used to typeset maybe one or more paragraphs (or minipages), but do not advance *vertically* the content that would appear immediately following this command. Are there anywhere some implementations of `\tlap` and `\blap`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Usually I define those by hand. I don't know any package that provides them. Roughly something like:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\tlap}[1]{\vbox to 0pt{\vss\hbox{#1}}}
\newcommand{\blap}[1]{\vbox to 0pt{\hbox{#1}\vss}}

\begin{document}

\hrulefill\blap{\shortstack{haha\\huhu}}\hrulefill
\tlap{\shortstack{haha\\huhu}}\hrulefill\par

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 16):

You can use `\raisebox` for this:

```
\raisebox{-\height}[0pt][0pt]{<content>}% blap
\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{<content>}% tlap, without changing the baseline
\raisebox{+\depth}[0pt][0pt]{<content>}% tlap, with lapping it completely upwards
```

As Stephane pointed out you can also use `\vbox to 0pt` and `\vss` for this.
See also my post and the discussion about this on `comp.text.tex`:
[Vertical versions of \llap and \rlap: \tlap and \blap](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/comp.text.tex/scharrer%2420tlap%2420blap/comp.text.tex/blS4Hmv9YuU/8r5yQtWf7dMJ)

I would write it now as follows to avoid any issues if used at the begin or between paragraphs:

```
\newcommand{\tlap}[1]{\mbox{\vbox to 0pt{\vss\hbox{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\blap}[1]{\mbox{\vbox to 0pt{\hbox{#1}\vss}}}
```

Comment: but that would require me to measure the `\height` or `\depth`, no?

Comment: @Juan: `\raisebox` does this for you. It stores the content in a register for this, so using `\vbox` is more efficient, but you have more freedom with `\raisebox`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `\smash`
Here a small introduction:
[TUGboat, Volume 22 (2001), No. 4](http://math.arizona.edu/~aprl/publications/mathclap/perlis_mathclap_24Jun2003.pdf)

Comment: Thanks, that works but seems to be something like `\tlap` while I was looking for `\blap`.

Comment: This works similar like `\tlap` without changing the baseline, but not for `\blap` or for lapping it complete upwards including the depth. Good article BTW, I wanted to link to it as well.

Comment: Just for information, the Tugboat article referenced in the answer was published in TUGboat Volume 22, Number 4, December 2001, on page 350.

Comment: Reading the linked article leaves me wondering how come it doesn't mention `\hidewidth` *at all*.

Answer (score 5):

The just-submitted `stackengine` package has vertical lapping commands built into it.  Furthermore, while the package defaults to a +/-`\baselineskip` vertical shift for the lap, that dimension may be tailored for your need.

In the example, below, I place a visible marker at the invocation site, so that you can see from where the lap is in reference to.

Hopefully, CTAN will propagate the package this weekend.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\parindent 0in\parskip 1em
\fboxsep=0pt\fboxrule=.1pt
\def\lapmark{\rule[-.3\baselineskip]{.1ex}{\baselineskip}}
\begin{document}
For illustration only, laps will be shown at a \textit{visible} lapmark
(given by \lapmark~), defining the point of invocation.  In these
examples, I lap a \verb|\parbox| above or below the selected location.

\begin{myverbbox}{\bll}\bllap\end{myverbbox}
\begin{myverbbox}{\brl}\brlap\end{myverbbox}
\begin{myverbbox}{\tll}\tllap\end{myverbbox}
\begin{myverbbox}{\trl}\trlap\end{myverbbox}
\begin{myverbbox}{\bcl}\bclap\end{myverbbox}
\begin{myverbbox}{\tcl}\tclap\end{myverbbox}
For example here\lapmark%
\bllap{\parbox[t]{.7in}{this is a bottom-left lap \bll}}
or el\lapmark%
\brlap{\parbox[t]{.8in}{this is a bottom-right lap \brl}}%
se here, or else I can put it here\lapmark%
\tllap{\parbox[b]{.7in}{this is a top-left lap \tll}}
or here\lapmark%
\trlap{\parbox[b]{.7in}{this is a top-right lap \trl}}%
.

Of course, I can per\lapmark
\bclap{\fbox{\parbox[t]{1.1in}{this is a bottom-center lap \bcl}}}%
form center lapping, as we\lapmark%
\tclap{\fbox{\parbox[b]{1.1in}{this is a top-center lap \tcl}}}%
ll.

\end{document}
```

[image]